Converting string to PDF file and then encoding file to base64 string .NET C#
I am using a third party API to send documents from a .NET C# application. The documents need to be base64 encoded string of a valid file format (.doc or .pdf or .jpg). The issue I'm having is that I want to send some additional data to this endpoint that is just a string e.g. "message". I also don't want to create any files in the directory.
So the approach I'm thinking of is:

Create a  file that doesn't get saved to disk and is a specific file format like pdf
Add text content to this file
Encode the whole file to a base64 string

I don't want to save the file anywhere, I just need to somehow create a file with the text content so I can encode it to base64.
But I'm unsure how to do this.
I'm pretty lost and would appreciate any help, guidance or opinions. Please correct me if I'm approaching this problem in the wrong way!
I've looked in MemoryMappedFiles and different libraries like PdfSharp but I was hoping to do this without adding another external dependency to the application. I tried programmatically creating a PDF file with the text content and then encoding that to a base64 string, but when I tried decoding the base64, the file I would get an error "Failed to load PDF document."
E.g.
            var text = "message";
            var textBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

            // Define PDF file header and footer
            const string pdfHeader = "%PDF-1.4\n";
            const string pdfFooter = "%%EOF";

            // Define PDF content with text
            var pdfContent = $"{pdfHeader}1 0 obj << /Length {textBytes.Length} >> stream\n{text}\nendstream\nendobj\n{pdfFooter}";

            // Convert the PDF text to a byte array
            var pdfBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pdfContent);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(pdfBytes);

This is the code I'm using to encode the other documents I'm sending to the API to base64 encoded string:

            using (var fileStream = fileStoreDal.GetLocalFileStream(path))
            {
                fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var documentBytes = fileStream.StreamToByteArray();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(documentBytes);
            }


You're really, really over-thinking here - just do Convert.ToBase64String( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "YourMessageGoesHere" ) ) - don't use Encoding.ASCII because it only acceptrs String values containing only ASCII-range (7-bit) chars and not the full range of Unicode codepoints in a C# String - so use Encoding.UTF8 instead.

This is what i was initially doing, but when I asked a stakeholder at the third party API company to verify he received the document, he said "seems like the messageDocument does not have a valid doc format". Which is why I thought I had to convert it to a valid document format (e.g. pdf) and then encode that to base64. When I decode a string using Convert.ToBase64String( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "YourMessageGoesHere" ) ) online and download the file, it's .txt which I'm guessing isn't valid for the API but waiting to hear back...

What you wrote there tells me that the third-party service is intending to only accept binary PDF and Office Word document files (which indeed have a defined binary format) - so why are you talking about wanting to send raw text/string messages? (but I'm not surprised the service detected it as .txt because all the bytes also can be validly interpreted as ASCII or UTF-8 characters.

Thanks for your replies! The third party API request doesn't have fields for all the data our customers provide us. So the workaround was to send the additional data as documents.. But it's proving very gross and I'm confused. Another option would be to just hide those fields on the frontend - that option is sounding appealing at this point!

BTW, your code to read a file into a Base64 string is somewhat inefficient because it  unnecessarily reads the entire file into memory first (which defeats the point of using a Stream) - also your call to Seek is redundant as files are opened at the start anyway. See my post here where I show how to be more memory-efficient when working with Base64.

I'd personally use a library to write a .pdf or .docx, etc. rather than manually trying to write a PDF myself.
